# Chromatic number and index of a graph formed by adding $5$ edges to the Petersen graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am asked to find the chromatic number and index of the graph below obtained by adding 5 edges to the Petersen graph. For the chromatic index, it must be either 4 or 5 ($\Delta$ or $\Delta + 1$). My intuition suggests that it is 5 because the Petersen subgraph requires 4 colors, and these colors cannot be used to color the additional edges. However, I'm struggling to provide specific answers. Additionally, although this graph is 4-vertex colorable, I am unable to demonstrate that it is not 3-vertex colorable or provide a 3-vertex coloring.

[image]

Comment: It's not $3$-vertex colorable because there is no independent set of $4$ vertices.

Answer (score 1):

I found the question interesting. Although there are actually two issues here.

1. The chromatic index of this graph is $4$ no matter how unexpected this looks. A suitable coloring of the edges of this graph is in the figure.

[image]

2. The chromatic number of this graph is also equal to $4$.
   Since it is very easy to color the vertices of the graph in four colors, it remains to prove that there is no coloring of three colors.
   This is where @user14111's hint really works.

   The maximal independent set consists of three vertices.
   (Just note that the cycles $1,2,3,4,5$ and $6,8,10,7,9$ cannot contain more than two independent vertices.)

   If the chromatic number of the graph were three, then all $10$ vertices of our graph could be partitioned into three (monochromatic) parts. At least one of the parts must have at least four vertices each. But then the graph has $4$ independent vertices. Which is impossible.